# Category and subcategory php

Tags: php, mysql

Hello i am trying to fix a thing as a beginner i am still learning `php` untill i consider i can migrate to a framework, what i am trying to do is:

1. I have a router in php like this :

   ```
   <?php 

        if(isset($_GET['contact'])){
            include('conctact.php');
        }elseif(isset($_GET['name_product'])){
            include('product.php');
        }else{
            include('home.php');
        }

    ?>
   ```
2. Links for menu like this:

   ```
    <?php 
       $select = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM products");
       while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select)){?>
           <div><a href="shoes/<?=$row['url_slug'];?>"><?=$row['name']?> - <?=$row['url_slug'];?></a></div>
    <?php } ?>
   ```

(Shoes is the category i want to add later dynamic category, on click i want to load page product.php, i dont want to have id on url so i did with url slug)

There is the `.htaccess`

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-])/([a-zA-Z0-9-])$   index.php?name_category=$name_product=$1 [L]
```

My url would like to look like this `www.example/shoes/product-name`

And the `product.php` looks like this:

```
<?php 

   $name_product = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['name_product']);

   $sql=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM products WHERE url_slug='$name_product '");

   $row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql);

 ?>
```

My table mysql looks like that:

```
Product table
|id|name|url_slug|category|

Category table
|id|name|
```

I don't know how to write that `.htaccess` when click on link to include page `product.php` and show details of product fetch from database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$   /index.php?name_category=$1&name_product=$2 [L]
```

Each set of brackets in your regex will get an own `$` variable.

This will match this exact url `www.example/shoes/product-name` like this:

`$1` = `shoes`

`$2` = `product-name`

So if your `url_slug` in your table is `product-name` you can use this to query your sql

`SELECT * FROM products WHERE url_slug='$name_product'`

Comment: Thanks for helping me, when i click on link is not include `product.php` my conditional from index.php is like a router, when i click on link my url looks like that https://www.example.com/shoes/nike-red and error `Object not found!`, can you help me please?

Comment: My bad the rewrite-rule has to start with an `/` and `[]` needs a quantifier `+` in this case, which means occurs 1-n times - fixed it. `Object not found!` is a pretty arbitrary error-message without context.

Comment: You mean like this ? `RewriteRule ^/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-])$   index.php?name_category=$1&name_product=$2 [L]` The error what i receive is 404 i forgot to mention that.

Comment: Take a look at my answer. This is not what i wrote - i updated it.
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/intro.html

Comment: Thanks very much for helping me, one question when i am on page product all urls looks like this https://www.example.com/shoes/shoes/nike-red

Comment: have a look at this line: `href="shoes/<?=$row['url_slug'];`